# Naemon Check failure

Tags: nagios, thruk

I have a Naemon check that uses check_ldap plugin and passes the password as macro. Command returns  OK on running manually on the server, however it shows Critical on thruk UI.
Uses below flags : -H, -b, -p, -D, -3, -P, -a, -S

Passing incorrect password on manually run returns same error code as visible on thruk.

Comment: What is the question you're asking us? Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sometimes it's because of a password that has special characters that aren't properly escaped. You may need to do some testing.